# Laravel 5.3 check if notification is read

Tags: notifications, laravel-5.3

I am using database notifications in Laravel 5.3. Is there a function or property to check if the notification is read or not when looping through the user's notifications. Thanks in advance

Comment: `read_at` is `null` for the notifications which you can use in your checks.

Answer (score 3):

You can sure can.
There are in fact two methods available in Laravel to check whether notifications

- [read](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Notifications/DatabaseNotification.html#method_read)
- [unread](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Notifications/DatabaseNotification.html#method_unread)

So you can do something like this in your Blade template:

```
@foreach(auth()->user()->notifications as $notification)
    ...
    @if($notification->unread())<badge>@lang('app.new')</badge>@endif
    ...
@endforeach
```

You can also query `Notification` collection with these methods.

Answer (score 0):

In the newer versions of laravel (6.2+), you can get all, read or unread notifications as collection. So, to get all read notifications, you can do something like:

```
@foreach (Auth::user()->readNotifications as $notification)
    // process $notification     
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take unreaded and readed notification seperately if you want

```
  $unreadedNotifications = Auth::user()->unreadNotifications();

  if($unreadedNotifications->count() > 0){}

  $readedNotifications = Auth::user()->readNotifications()->get();
  if($readedNotifications->count() > 0){}
```